# Find a Lebesgue integrable function which satisfies a convolution equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative Lebesgue integrable function with integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$ equals to 1. Let $\tilde{f}(x)=f(-x)$. Suppose $f$ satisfies the following equation:
$$
f \ast \left( \log \frac{1}{f \ast \tilde{f}} \right) = c,
$$
where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is some constant. How do I find such a function $f$ which solves the above condition?

I have tried using Laplace transforms but the logarithmic function is making it hard to obtain any progress. Can any one help me solve this?

One can also take $n=1$ for simplicity.

Comment: wait !!! you mean $\hat{f}$ is NOT the Fourier transform of $f$ ?? it is just $f(-x)$ ??? in the context of convolutions and Laplace transform, $\hat{f}$ ALWAYS denotes the Fourier transform of $f$ so change that write $g(x) = f(-x)$

Answer (score 1):

Taking Fourier transforms turns the outer convolution into a product and the constant into a Dirac delta. Since the Fourier transform of f is continuous this shows that that of $\log f*\tilde{f}$ must be a Dirac delta. Hence the logarithm must be a constant and so must the inner convolution. Take Fourier transforms of this inner convolution and you see the product of the Fourier transforms must be a Dirac delta which is not possible for the product of two continuous functions

Comment: How do we prove that the Fourier transform of a Lebesgue integrable function is continuous?

Comment: This is the first fact you usually learn about fourier transforms and is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem together with the fact that all exponentials $ \exp (I \omega x)$ are bounded by 1 in absolute value

Comment: Thanks, I knew the fact but not the proof.